# Need help getting the output of a function as the value of an input form

Tags: javascript

So im trying to create a form that will send the date of the next friday as the value. The value should be in the form "YYYY-MM-DD"

Here is what i have so far:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next_charge_scheduled_at" id="s1" value="" />
<script type="text/javascript">
 var elem = document.getElementById("s1");
elem.value = function()
{
var d = new Date();

switch (d.getDay())
{
case 0: d.setDate(d.getDate() + 5);
break;

case 1: d.setDate(d.getDate() + 4);
break;

case 2: d.setDate(d.getDate() + 3);
break;

case 3: d.setDate(d.getDate() + 2);
break;

case 4: d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
break;

case 6: d.setDate(d.getDate() + 6);
break;
}

return d;

};
</script>
```

However, this returns the whole function, and not the result, as far as i can see.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why did you assign a `function` to `elem.value`?

Comment: I edited my code and add another case to switch, case 5: d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);
break; check if it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a function, only if we excute the function like so `calculateFriday()` we will get the value which we will set to the input field!

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("s1");
elem.value = calculateFriday();

function calculateFriday() {
  var d = new Date();

  switch (d.getDay()) {
    case 0:
      d.setDate(d.getDate() + 5);
      break;

    case 1:
      d.setDate(d.getDate() + 4);
      break;

    case 2:
      d.setDate(d.getDate() + 3);
      break;

    case 3:
      d.setDate(d.getDate() + 2);
      break;

    case 4:
      d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
      break;

    case 5:
      d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);
      break;

    case 6:
      d.setDate(d.getDate() + 6);
      break;
  }
  return moment(d).format('YYYY-MM-DD');;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" tname="next_charge_scheduled_at" id="s1" value="" />
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked great! 
The only problem now, is that it's outputting todays date (because its friday) 
How can i get it to skip todays date, and choose the next friday?

Answer (score 3):

You have binded a function to elem.value.If you want to put the result of function to elem.value,do it in this way:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next_charge_scheduled_at" id="s1" value="" />
<script type="text/javascript">
 var elem = document.getElementById("s1");
    elem.value=getDate();

    function getDate()
    {
    var d = new Date();

    switch (d.getDay())
    {
    case 0: d.setDate(d.getDate() + 5);
    break;

    case 1: d.setDate(d.getDate() + 4);
    break;

    case 2: d.setDate(d.getDate() + 3);
    break;

    case 3: d.setDate(d.getDate() + 2);
    break;

    case 4: d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
    break;

    case 5: d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);
    break;

    case 6: d.setDate(d.getDate() + 6);
    break;
    }

    return `${d.getFullYear()}-${(d.getMonth() + 1) }-${d.getDate()}`;

    };
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked great! The only problem now, is that it's outputting todays date (because its friday) How can i get it to skip todays date, and choose the next friday?